# Charting JSON data - Javascript direct from IBM Cloudant (bluemix no-sql) database? Pls help a N00b

Tags: javascript, json, charts, ibm-cloud, cloudant

Ok, so I'm working on an Internet of Things project and REALLY need your help. I have an arduino sending time stamped temperature data as MQTT packets to cloud servers (IBM Bluemix) and storing them to a no-sql database (Cloudant). What I want to do is access and graph this data from a webapp but I'm a total N00b.

From my research it looks like I need a javascript chart library that can read JSON data. I want to read it direct from my lovely cloud DB that has a HTTP API.

For example, you can view my actual data here:
http://viztech.mybluemix.net/showtemps

A single entry in the DB looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": "77b618c9a049aed2fee44bd62fa5913a",
    "_rev": "1-909bab171a80e147b0df0c1939242db7",
    "topic": "iot-2/type/iotsample-arduino/id/deedbafefeed/evt/status/fmt/json",
    "payload": {
        "d": {
```

```
                "temp": 32.52,
                "timestamp": 1439476189
```

```
         }
    },
    "deviceId": "deedbafefeed",
    "deviceType": "iotsample-arduino",
    "eventType": "status",
    "format": "json",
    "msgid": "1c7ede24.e38122"
}
```

I just want to know how to chart the payload! Do I need to extract the payload into a separate data structure of some sort and then chart, or is there a library that can do it direct or something? I am really new to this. Would greatly appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Dan.

Answer (score 1):

The Bluemix IoT Foundation has sample recipes which include one for [visualization](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/visualizing-your-data/).  I think this may be helpful for you, it uses the Rickshaw charting library. 
sample code here - 
https://github.com/ibm-messaging/iot-visualization

Comment: Thanks for the reply Valerie. Much appreciated. Back in my computer science days of 2004 everything was SQL. The emerging tech seems to be HTTP API's. Very cool. Very different to what I know :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on charting, but depending on your library of choice you will need to supply the data in a different format. So I would suggest to choose a framework like [D3.js](http://d3js.org/), [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/), ..  and extract and transform the payload to whatever you need.

I highly doubt there is going to be a one-to-one mapping from your Cloudant payload to your desired charting input.

Comment: Ok thanks Driss! I've had a look at D3.js and it seems very popular. Still a bit of a steep learning curve but will have a crack. Dan

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if it helped you, @DanielBaker ;-) In any case you will need to pick some sort of visualization framework (unless you like inviting the wheel again) and put your data inside it following the structure they use.